# Clickable Buttons on JTree panels?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need to rewrite some legacy JTree code to make implementation of coming features easier. This code creates three icons for each node (see screenshot, in red boxes) which perform some action when clicked.

Those icons are contained in a JPanel which is created by a custom TreeRenderer.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4pHS.png)

the current code counts pixels to figure out which icon was clicked, i.e.

```
if (x >= 0 && x <= 9) {
                if (y >= 4 && y <= 12) {
                    gpxObj.setVisible(!gpxObj.isVisible());                    
                }
            } else if (x >= 13 && x <= 19) {
...
```

I tried to replace this code by implementing these icons as `JButton`s with an `ActionLister()` each, but it looks like the mouse click is intercepted by the `JTree` and never reaches the buttons `ActionListener()`.

how else can this functionality be implemented? Do I need to implement a `TreeCellEditor` or similar?

thanks in advance.